# Dependency Injection .NET: Use static service descriptors to avoid performance/resource issues?

Tags: .net, performance, dependency-injection

I am working with various nested packages, which register DI services. Some of them are, unavoidably, being added multiple times to the *IServiceCollection*.

I started to define DI in static collections, using the *IServiceCollection* for *.AddTransient()*, *AddSingleton()* etc.

Is this useful, or does it not harm to add equivalent services multiple times?

```
public static class DIRegistrations
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor> FrequentlyAddedServices 
        = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddTransient<IFrequentlyAddedService1, FrequentlyAddedService1>()
        .AddTransient<IFrequentlyAddedService2, FrequentlyAddedService2>();
    
    
    public static IServiceCollection UseFrequentlyAddedServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        return serviceCollection.TryAdd(FrequentlyAddedServices);
    }
}
```

A variation could be to check already existing instances by reference (Microsoft *TryAdd()* compares the service/interface).

Otherwise, the *AddTransient()* calls would be executed multiple times.

Comment: `Some of them are, unavoidably, being added multiple times to the IServiceCollection.` what does this mean? And why would it matter? Do you get an error? `I started to define DI in static collections,` you're creating new DI containers, not static collections. You'll end up with different services depending on which of those DI containers you use in the end. As for `TryAdd`, you can already use that with your services.

Comment: In the example, the `UseFrequentlyAddedServices()` would be called multiple times, from other DI setiups, which must ensure that FrequentlyAddedServices are present. The `ServiceCollection` in the static field is only to use the `.Add...()` extensions, therefore only an `IEnumerable<ServiceDescriptor>` outwards.

Comment: `TryAdd...()` looks good, as long as the same service/interface doesn't need to be added multiple times in different variations, or overwritten (have another implementation added later, to replace the former).